# Implementing Immutable, Growable Vectors

Tags: data-structures, f#, clojure, functional-programming

I'm interested in implementing persistent (e.g. purely functional, immutable, etc), growable vectors in F#, so that they might be used in the .NET framework. My current implementation is a variant on the Hash-Mapped Trie, and is done according to [Clojure's implementation](http://blog.higher-order.net/2009/02/01/understanding-clojures-persistentvector-implementation/).

I'm having trouble implementing random-access insertions and deletions (inserting and removing elements at random indices) using this implementation. Is there some algorithm/modification that allows these operations efficiently, or some other implementation I can look at?

*Clarification:* When I say 'inserts' and 'deletes' I mean, for example, given the list `[1; 2; 3; 4]` an insert of `500` in position `1` will give me `[1:500:2:3:4]`. I don't mean a `set` or `associate` operation.

Comment: [FSharpx's Vector](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/DataStructures/Vector.fs) is ported from Clojure's PersistentVector. It seems to be close to what you need.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't support random-access inserts and deletions. Though it's nice to have something that's written in F#. Though my implementation isn't a direct port.

Comment: Actually we have assocN, but it's in the experimental branch. https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Collections.Experimental/Vector.fs#L439

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Finger trees](http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/slides/soda98.pdf) might be what you are looking for. There is a [Clojure implementation](https://github.com/clojure/data.finger-tree) available.

Comment: Finger trees won't allow me insert an item into the middle of the list. :( thanks though.

Comment: @GregRos No, but finger trees have O(log(n)) splitting, concatting, and insertion at the end. The idea is that you implement "insert in the middle" as "split into left and right halves, append to left list, concat results". That said, I've heard that finger trees are asymptotically good, but practically poor.

Answer (score 1):

Immutable vectors/lists typically provide fast updates by only allowing insertions at one end and then sharing the immutable data at the other end. If you want to do non-head/tail insertions what you're actually wanting to do is mutate the immutable end of your collection. You'll have to split the vector around the item you want to insert and then splice it back together to create a new vector, and the best you're going to be able to do it in is *O(n)* time.

Immutable sorted trees work a little bit differently, but they won't let you re-number indicies (keys) in less than *O(n)* time either.

Basically, if someone had discovered an efficient way to support random-access insertions in an immutable vector then it would be supported in one of the mainstream functional languages—but there is no such known data structure or algorithm, so there's no such implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing can do is split and join. This is very ineffective with clojure vectors. That is why Phill Bagwell implmented a persistent vector that can be split and join in log(n).

You might want to look at this video: http://blip.tv/clojure/phill-bagwell-striving-to-make-things-simple-and-fast-5936145

or directly to his paper here: infoscience.epfl.ch/record/169879/files/RMTrees.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Port the [Haskell HAMT library](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unordered-containers/0.2.2.1/doc/html/src/Data-HashMap-Base.html#HashMap)? The [Insert operation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unordered-containers/0.2.2.1/doc/html/src/Data-HashMap-Base.html#insert) is *O(log n)*

Comment: The insertion operation here is a `set` or `associate` operations. It overwrites the value previously associated there.

Comment: Sure. `"If this map previously contained a mapping for
-- the key, the old value is replaced."` But do you want a mutable insert, or an immutable one? Both are possible. Or do you require sequential integer indexing? If so, look at [finger trees](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.2.0.1/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html)..